# Styling and restarting an application

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am styling my application and changing the color in runtime. However I want to use gradient and using different gradients nuggets such as `pancake, magic gradients` even just using xamarin forms work fine until I use dynamic resource which is already reported bug so I must use static which in iOS doesn't change as I am not restating the app as in android.

Is there a way in iOS to restart the application? In android I just call `On Activity`, but it seems that iOS prevents this.

Is there any other way?

Comment: First of all, although it is possible to force kill your app, this is not allowed by Apple because of apple's policy .In addition, there is no way to restart your app once it's killed.

Comment: so there is no way to solve this